# Symfony doctrine QueryBuilder как указать AS для expr()->count

Tags: запрос, symfony3, doctrine

Есть такой запрос:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb->leftJoin('u.admin', 'admin')
->Select($qb->expr()->count('admin'))
->addSelect('admin.username')
->addGroupBy('admin.username');
```

В результате получаю:

```
array(1) { [0]=&gt;  array(2) {    [1]=&gt;
int(1)
["username"]=&gt;
string(5) "admin"  }}
```

Но хотелось бы полностью ассоциативный массив. Можно ли для expr()->count задать псевдоним ? Как если бы было написано
`->Select('Count(admin.id) AS Counter')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что Вам мешает сделать вот так, к примеру?

```
    $e = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
    $qb = $e->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->join('u.statictics', 's')
        ->select('COUNT(s.id) as sCnt')
        ->addSelect('u.username')
        ->addGroupBy('u.username')
    ;
```

Comment: По итогу так и сделал.